# Incorrect formatting of table with graphics inside using centering statements

Tags: tables, graphics, rowcolor

I am trying to produce this beautiful table with ducks.

I have two formatting issues that are connected:

- the most annoying one is that when zooming on the table
  the white `\Xhline` or the color bands are slightly uneven when looking at the left edge there is a line break (cf zoomed picture)[image: zoomed picture]. It looks like it is a detail but on my true example at home the line break is really showing for some reasons.
- the second super annoying issue is that on the right edge I cannot use a simple centering statement as they either break the next line because they are not ended properly or when ended using `{\centering }` it does not produce the correct result in terms of margin. I had to resort to `\hfil`.

Below a fully contained MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\definecolor{bubblegum}{rgb}{0.99, 0.76, 0.8}
\newcommand\thickhline{\Xhline{2pt}}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikzducks}



\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering

\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\small
\color{white}\sffamily
 \begin{tabular}{@{} >{\color{black}} m{30mm} @{}>{\color{black}} m{30mm} @{}>{\color{black}} m{30mm} @{}>{\color{black}} m{30mm}  @{}>{\color{black}} m{30mm} @{}>{\color{black}} m{30mm} @{}>{\color{black}} m{30mm} @{}>{\color{black}} m{30mm} } 
 \thickhline
 \rowcolor{gray}
 \centering Lorem & \centering Ipsum & \centering Lorem & \centering Ipsum & \centering Lorem & \centering Ipsum & \centering Lorem & {\hfil Ipsum} \\ [0.5ex] 
  \thickhline

 \rowcolor{lightgray}
\centering \textbf{Lorem} & \centering Ipsum & \centering Lorem & \centering Ipsum & \centering Lorem & \centering Ipsum & \centering Lorem & {\hfil Ipsum} \\
  \thickhline
  \rowcolor{Ivory2}
\centering \textbf{Lorem} & \centering Ipsum  & \centering Lorem & \centering Ipsum & \centering Lorem & \centering Ipsum[![enter image description here][1]][1] & \centering Ipsum & {\hfil Lorem} \\
 \thickhline
  \rowcolor{LightSkyBlue2}
\centering \textbf{Images} 
& \centering \adjincludegraphics[width=30mm, height=30mm, valign=b]{example-image-duck} 
& \centering \includegraphics[width=30mm, height=30mm, valign=b]{example-image-duck} 
& \centering \includegraphics[width=30mm, height=30mm, valign=b]{example-image-duck} 
& \centering \includegraphics[width=30mm, height=30mm, valign=b]{example-image-duck} 
& \centering \includegraphics[width=30mm, height=30mm, valign=b]{example-image-duck} 
& \centering \includegraphics[width=30mm, height=30mm, valign=b]{example-image-duck} 
& {\hfil \includegraphics[width=30mm, height=30mm, valign=b]{example-image-duck} \par} \\

 \hline
 \end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: use `\tabularnewline` to end the tabular lines, ``\\``  conflicts with centering. Use the overhang argument of \rowcolor to avoid that it overwrites the pictures. \rowcolor{LightSkyBlue2}[0pt] . Never use \resizebox around a tabular, this gives bad font sizes. And don't ask to many questions in one question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ulrike Fischer it turns out point 1 and 2 are answered by removing hfil using your \tabularneline trick.

Comment: I asked several questions into one because I thought they were entertwined, which turned out to be the case. However when applying the \tabularnewline fixes the pictures lose their blue margins which I like ([0pt] doesn't give me what I want). Would you also have an idea on how to fix the margins of the pictures ?

Comment: Why do you use @{} in the preamble? It removes the space between the cell.

Comment: If I remove them it doesn't fix the margin above and below the pictures which are at 0 and it introduces an artifact of vertical white lines separating the cells.

Comment: well that is the reason why it is bad to mix different questions and to create a too large example: I have now no idea what you changed and what not and discussing that in the comment is up to impossible.

Comment: Ok I will restrict the question scope and let you answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Ulrike Fischer's comment a complete code fixing the table by getting rid of the unwanted line breaks while keeping margins around each of the figure would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\definecolor{bubblegum}{rgb}{0.99, 0.76, 0.8}
\newcommand\thickhline{\Xhline{2pt}}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikzducks}



\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering

\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\small
\color{white}\sffamily
 \begin{tabular}{@{} >{\color{black}} m{30mm} @{} >{\color{black}} m{30mm} @{} >{\color{black}} m{30mm} @{} >{\color{black}} m{30mm} @{} >{\color{black}} m{30mm} @{} >{\color{black}} m{30mm} @{} >{\color{black}} m{30mm} @{} >{\color{black}} m{30mm} } 
 \thickhline
 \rowcolor{gray}
 \centering Lorem & \centering Ipsum & \centering Lorem & \centering Ipsum & \centering Lorem & \centering Ipsum & \centering Lorem & \centering Ipsum \tabularnewline [0.5ex] 
  \thickhline

 \rowcolor{lightgray}
\centering \textbf{Lorem} & \centering Ipsum & \centering Lorem & \centering Ipsum & \centering Lorem & \centering Ipsum & \centering Lorem & \centering Ipsum \tabularnewline
  \thickhline
  \rowcolor{Ivory2}
\centering \textbf{Lorem} & \centering Ipsum  & \centering Lorem & \centering Ipsum & \centering Lorem & \centering ? & \centering Ipsum & \centering Lorem \tabularnewline
 \thickhline
  \rowcolor{LightSkyBlue2}
\centering \textbf{Images} 
& \centering \vspace{2mm} \adjincludegraphics[width=26mm, height=26mm, valign=m]{example-image-duck} \vspace{2mm}
& \centering \vspace{2mm} \includegraphics[width=26mm, height=26mm, valign=m]{example-image-duck} \vspace{2mm}
& \centering \vspace{2mm} \includegraphics[width=26mm, height=26mm, valign=m]{example-image-duck} \vspace{2mm}
& \centering \vspace{2mm} \includegraphics[width=26mm, height=26mm, valign=m]{example-image-duck} \vspace{2mm}
& \centering \vspace{2mm} \includegraphics[width=26mm, height=26mm, valign=m]{example-image-duck} \vspace{2mm}
& \centering \vspace{2mm} \includegraphics[width=26mm, height=26mm, valign=m]{example-image-duck} \vspace{2mm}
& \centering \vspace{2mm} \includegraphics[width=26mm, height=26mm, valign=m]{example-image-duck} \vspace{2mm} \tabularnewline

 \hline
 \end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here is the results:
[image]
Note that the use of vspace is slightly ugly and that valign are a bit useless.